# VC++ 2010 - Undeclared Identifier in attempt at DLL, small amount of code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, x86

C++ newbie here. I'm trying to put some WIA functions in a DLL. I keep getting and undeclared identifier on the IWiaDevMgr variable.  When creating the project I chose the Win32 Console Application and DLL application type. Not sure if it matters but I put the wiaguid.lib in the project
`properties -> Linker -> input -> additional dependencies`.

What is wrong with this code?

MyDLL.h

```
#include <wia.h>
namespace MyDLL
{
    class MyFirstFuncs
    {
        public:
              static __declspec(dllexport) int doWork();      
    };
}
```

MyDLL.cpp

```
#include "MyDLL.h"
namespace MyDLL
{
    int MyFirstFuncs::doWork()
    {
         IWiaDevMgr *pIWiaDevMgr;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you get the error in dll project or in another module that uses the dll?

Comment: Can you post the actual code? Also, the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I presume this *is* the actual code, but we're missing the `DllEntryPoint` function (and the source files that contain it). It seems strange to create a Console application if you're trying to create a DLL.

Comment: I think he'd get a compiler error, because `doWork()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'm just trying to build a DLL because I need to get access to some native windows functions in my Java program.  There is nothing loading it yet.  When I build it, I get error C2065: 'IWiaDevMgr' : undeclared identifier.  
error C2065: 'pIWiaDevMgr' : undeclared identifier.    That is the whole code by the way.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Through trial and error I found that

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wia.h>
```

fixed the problem.

I'm a C++ newbie also so couldn't tell you the exact reason why this works. Probably WIA is dependant on some definitions/macros/whatever in WINDOWS.H

Answer (score 0):

Check the order in which you have included your header files. It may be the same problem like the one I had in programming a Directshow application. I had included vmr9.h before d3d9.h. During the build process, the compiler fired errors concerning d3d9 objects included in the vmr9.h. I had to reorder the inclusions to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that is the whole code and there is only one header file.